# URI scheme is not "file" plug in error

Tags: java, file, eclipse-plugin, uri, epsilon

I am getting the error

> URI scheme is not “file”

after I run the plugin that I am trying to create. The error is thrown from the following method :

```
protected File getFile(String fileName) throws URISyntaxException {
    System.out.println(fileName);

    URI binUri = EpsilonStandaloneExample.class.getResource(fileName).toURI();
    URI uri = null;
    System.out.println(uri);
    if (binUri.toString().indexOf("bin") > -1) {
        uri = new URI(binUri.toString().replaceAll("bin", "src"));
    }
    else {
        uri = binUri;
    }
    System.out.println(uri);
    return new File(uri);
}
```

When I run my class as a java application everything is working and i am getting the right path which is:

```
file:/E:/epsilon-eclipse/workspace/Test2/src/org/eclipse/epsilon/examples/standalone/egl/oxfordDriver.egl
```

Now that i am implementing a plugin and run this code the URI returned is:

```
bundleresource://652.fwk1463565218/org/eclipse/epsilon/examples/standalone/egl/oxfordDriver.egl
```

This URI is not correct and thats why the error is thrown.

Any suggestions of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to load a file which is part of the resources in your plugin. This is not possible using a file path, as all resources in a plugin are resolved using a bundle relative URL (and the bundle itself might be deployed as jar file, so there even isn't a normal file). Have a look at [reading resources from a plugin](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/).

Also make sure that you [add those files to your build.properties](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/build.htm) (see section "Binary build"). It is not enough to have the files lying around in the plugin project.